# Embedded method when creating OnChildClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set up an onChildClickListener in my MainActivity class I just want to show a toast when they select an option, but I get an error with the code below. It doesn't recognize "this".

I'm guessing this is because the method is embedded, but I can't figure out how to take it out and declare it somewhere else so that it recognizes "this" activity.

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

```
onCreate(){ 
...
 eListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To take the embedded methods out and into the class use the implements keyword.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html

The IDE will probably figure out the imports and the IDE will make the stub methods for you ...Nice...So I'm not showing that part of the code.

```
public class Play extends Activity implements OnChildClickListener{
```

Comment: Actually implements is my favorite part of java android because implemented methods can be call by other fragments as done here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728510/application-crashes-when-i-set-an-onclicklistener/19729302#19729302  makes it easier to test methods from another class.

Answer (score 0):

The ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener you've created is an anonymous inner class.

Anonymous inner classes have a reference to their outer class's this.  When you want to use the outer class' this, you need to prefix it with the outer class name like so:

```
onCreate(){ 
...
 eListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```